# OpenCL NDrangekernel with 3d global size and 3d local size

Tags: opencl

I am trying to compute local sum of each group by identify with 3d volume position and group ID.

My idea is divide space into groups and use atomic_add to compute local_sum.
But because I am new to parallel computing so it is kind of hard to find the correlation between codes and instructions.
My current kernel is like:

```
__kernel void TestAtomicAddLocal(__global *int src, int3 size, __global int *res)
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    int z = get_global_id(2);
    if( x >= vol_dim.x || y >= vol_dim.y || z >= vol_dim.z ){ return; }
    int id = x + y * vol_dim.x + z * vol_dim.x * vol_dim.y; 

   // local mem shared by all work items in work group, 
   //so this can be accessed by all items in current workgroup 
    __local int local_sum;
    local_sum= 0;

    // use global_id to access the value of input array
    int local_offset = atomic_add(&local_sum, src[id]);
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    int global_offset = atomic_add(&num_verts[0], local_sum);
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

For the host part, my setting is

```
enqueueNDrangeKernel( cq, kn_testAtomicAddLocal, 3, 0, cl::size3(256,256,256), cl::size3(64, 64, 64), 0, 0, 0);
```

For kenrnel arguments, the *src is `cl_mem` with size `256*256*256*sizeof(cl_int)`, size is `4 * sizeof(cl_int)`, and *res is `cl_mem` with size `4*sizeof(int)`. 
Then I get error that CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCE and CL_INVALID_GROUP_SIZE, from my understanding, my device max group size is 1024, but here total group = (256/64)^3 = 64 < 1024.
My gpu max work item size is 1024x1024x64 which is also ok. So I think there must something I understand is wrong. I hope someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max group size limits your 64 * 64 * 64 part.

And I guess you are using a CUDA card. You'd better use CUDA on CUDA cards. OpenCL is more or less emulated on CUDA cards. If you are not, I thinks all AMD cards have a group size limit of 256. edit: Um... I forgot about Intel ones. If so, ignore this part.

One more important thing, you'd better check some reduction logic implementation example on the internet first. Atomics are very expesive and using them like what you did would almost certain make your GPU code slower than CPU ones.

Comment: I am using CUDA card, but my program needs to be ran on all kinds of graphics card so I have to use OpenCL. You mean like a local reduce and global reduce instead of two atomic_add in different domain right? I just want to not write too many kernel function in my kernel file. Could you recommend my some resource of OpenCL?

Comment: @EdwinDebuger I remember there are samples in AMD's SDK, but I'm not sure. I think for your case, you can just use smaller block an let one thread handle more than on element.

Comment: @EdwinDebuger And a more general solution is to do local reduction on GPU and than do a global reduction on CPU. But still you will need do a per-thread local-local reduction before doing the per-group reduction. And the optimal count of the groups is determined by the capacity of the GPU not the size of the job.